# How is the original num2 updated in this fibonacci instance?

Tags: javascript, function, fibonacci

I've been given an instance of code and expected of to explain it.

```
    function fib(num1, num2, stop) {
      var num3 = num1 + num2;
      console.log(num3);
      if(stop === 0) {
          return;
      }
      fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);
    }

fib(0, 1, 6)
```

While It seems I get all of it, I cannot seem to fathom how does the parameter num2 keeps being updated to the next number.

- In this instance of code we're suppose to log the numbers according to the fibonacci sequence up until and including the 6th index.

Thanks!

P.S. This is my first time posting on stackoverflow, if anyone has any tips on how to better this post for example. I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> how does the parameter num2 keeps being updated to the next number.

Actually `num2` is never updated. However, every recursive execution of `fib` introduces a *new* variable with that same name. And it gets its value from the caller. Once it has that value, it never changes. But you get as many variables with that name `num2` as there are calls to `fib`.

Now note how the recursive call is made:

```
fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);
```

And then check how these arguments are *received*:

```
function fib(num1, num2, stop) {
```

Note that the `num3` of the caller, becomes the initial value of `num2` of the *called*. This gives the impression that `num2` *changes* throughout this program, but it is actually a new variable each time a "change" occurs, and the initial value is always what `num3` has in the calling execution context.

### Visualisation

Each "box" in the below diagram represents a single execution context of `fib`. It is a container for a set of local variables. These remain untouched while yet a deeper call is made to a function, because *that* will result in yet another context (container) for a new set of variables:

```
fib(0, 1, 6)
+-------- new execution context ---------------------------------------------+
| // num1 = 0, num2 = 1, stop = 6                                            |
| var num3 = num1 + num2; // = 1                                             |
| fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);                                                 |
|     +------ new execution context ----------------------------------------+|
|     | // num1 = 1, num2 = 1, stop = 5                                     ||
|     | var num3 = num1 + num2; // = 2                                      ||
|     | fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);                                          ||
|     |     +------ new execution context ---------------------------------+||
|     |     | // num1 = 1, num2 = 2, stop = 4                              |||
|     |     | var num3 = num1 + num2; // = 3                               |||
|     |     | fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);                                   |||
|     |     |     +------ new execution context --------------------------+|||
|     |     |     | // num1 = 2, num2 = 3, stop = 3                       ||||
|     |     |     | var num3 = num1 + num2; // = 5                        ||||
|     |     |     | fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);                            ||||
|     |     |     |     +------ new execution context -------------------+||||
|     |     |     |     | // num1 = 3, num2 = 5, stop = 2                |||||
|     |     |     |     | var num3 = num1 + num2; // = 8                 |||||
|     |     |     |     | fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);                     |||||
|     |     |     |     |     +------ new execution context ------------+|||||
|     |     |     |     |     | // num1 = 5, num2 = 8, stop = 1         ||||||
|     |     |     |     |     | var num3 = num1 + num2; // = 13         ||||||
|     |     |     |     |     | fib(num2, num3, stop - 1);              ||||||
|     |     |     |     |     |     +------ new execution context -----+||||||
|     |     |     |     |     |     | // num1 = 8, num2 = 13, stop = 0 |||||||
|     |     |     |     |     |     +----------------------------------+||||||
|     |     |     |     |     +-----------------------------------------+|||||
|     |     |     |     +------------------------------------------------+||||
|     |     |     +-------------------------------------------------------+|||
|     |     +--------------------------------------------------------------+||
|     +---------------------------------------------------------------------+|
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thx, seems so obvious now, to be frank